How to setup react-native-branch with expo managed workflow?
I am following branch.io react native setup tutorial and it says that i have to do the following:

Configure Info.plist file.
Add the file to your project using Xcode. Within your project,
navigate to File → Add Files.
To initialize Branch on iOS, add the following to your app's AppDelegate file:

I am confused, because I do not have info.plist file, I am not using xcode and i don't have appdelegate file as well, because everything is managed by expo.
What steps do I have to follow if I want to use react-native-branch using expo?

use @config-plugins/react-native-branch which is an Expo maintained plugin for configuring the native code required for react-native-branch

Branch.io deep linking is not directly compatible with the Expo managed workflow. This is because Branch requires specific native code configurations and access to early lifecycle methods, which the managed workflow restricts.
However, there are some workarounds and alternatives you can explore:
Expo Config Plugins:
Expo offers config plugins (like @config-plugins/react-native-branch) that aim to simplify the integration process. These plugins attempt to inject the necessary Branch configurations during the build process.
However, this method has limitations and might not cover all Branch features due to the managed workflow's constraints.
Expo Bare Workflow:
The Expo bare workflow provides more control over native code, making it easier to integrate Branch directly.
You can convert your Expo managed project to a bare workflow if deep linking with Branch is a priority.
Alternative Deep Linking Libraries:
Consider using other deep linking libraries compatible with Expo, like react-navigation's deep linking features or expo-linking. These might offer a simpler solution if you don't need all the advanced functionalities of Branch.
Custom Development Client:
With the Expo development client, you can make changes to the native code. You can utilize this to integrate the Branch SDK into your application's native code. This approach requires more development experience, as you'll be working directly with the native codebase.
Important Considerations:
Expo SDK Version:
The feasibility and specific steps for integrating Branch might vary depending on your Expo SDK version. Always refer to the latest Expo and Branch documentation for up-to-date instructions.
Community Support:
Explore the Expo forums and community resources like Stack Overflow for discussions and solutions related to integrating Branch with Expo. You might find valuable insights and workarounds shared by other developers.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

this is generated by an LLM. It is actually harder in the bare workflow, because you have to manually perform native code changes, which the config plugin does automatically for you. It is such a terrible idea to leave the managed workflow for something like this
